# Is it possible to use jsp login form as a custom login form for spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, spring-security

I have a spring boot project and all the views are jsp pages I tried to work with spring security but I couldn't use it with a jsp form I searched for similar examples but I didn't find a thing about it so my question is: is it possible to use jsp form as a custom login  page?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your create your own custom login page in Spring security

1. Create a custom page.
   For example  - create your custom login at auth folder in views with named login.jsp
2. In Spring security configuration file

   ```
    @Configuration
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
       private static final String LOGIN_URL = "/";
       private static final String LOGOUT_URL = "/logout";

       /**
       * Associate the specified URL with the view corresponding to that URL (the same as {@ code mvc: view - controller}).
       * <p>
       * In this class implementation, we only associate the login screen URL with the login screen view.
       * You won't be able to add model attributes through the controller registry. Instead, configure your InternalResourceViewResolver to expose beans to the JSP
       *(through request attributes, which is equivalent to what happens to model attributes). 
       *
       * @see org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter#addViewControllers(org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry)
       */
       @Override
           public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
               registry.addViewController(LOGIN_URL).setViewName("auth/login");
       }


       @Configuration
       @Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER)
       protected static class FormSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

           @Override
           protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

               http.formLogin()
                   .loginPage(LOGIN_URL);

               http.logout()
                   .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(LOGOUT_URL))
                   .logoutSuccessUrl(LOGIN_URL)
                   .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                   .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                   .clearAuthentication(true);
               }
           }
      }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your respond! Do you have an example with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter??

Comment: FormSecurity is a static inner class of SecurityConfiguration and extended by WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. For simplicity purpose i have written the code in one class. You can seperate it two different classes, one for Web configuration containing the addViewControllers method and another security related purpose extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.